# Swift split view controller, issue with "repeat" Notification on first load

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, notifications, nsfetchedresultscontroller

### Full title: Swift 4.2 using split view controller, issue with "repeat" Notification on first load that disrupts ability to programmatically select a "new" object in the Master Table View.

**Background**

I am working with a split view controller with master and detail table views - **master** is a plain dynamic table view that displays a list of entities to the user and **detail** is a grouped dynamic table view that displays the attributes and relationship values for the user-selected entity in the master.

I have implemented Core Data.

The master table view shows a list of entities. The data source for the master table view is a fetched results controller.

The detail table view shows the attributes and associated relationship values of the currently selected row (entity) in the master table view. The data source for the detail table view is the entity relating to the currently selected row in the master table view, which it is passed using a "Show Detail" segue.

On devices with larger screens where `splitViewController.isCollapsed == false`, the master and detail table views are both active on screen, per the image below.

[image: Master and Detail table views on screen using iPad Pro 2nd gen simulator]

Fairly standard arrangement for a data driven app...?

**Logic Flow**

When a user updates an existing entity (in the case of the screenshot example, an existing "Event"), they click the the `Save` button in the navigation bar of the detail table view.

Because the entity already exists, in the Master Table View Controller's `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath)` Fetched Results Controller Delegate method:

- under `case .update`, implement `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)`, which triggers `tableView(_willDisplay:forRowAt:)` which in turn updates the formatting of the selected Table View Cell; AND
- under `case .insert`, `case .update` and `case .move`, I set a temporary value for the current IndexPath `indexPathForManagedObjectChanged`

The Fetched Results Controller Delegate method:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
            indexPathForManagedObjectChanged = newIndexPath
            print("___controllerDidChangeObject: INSERTED OBJECT")
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
            print("___controllerDidChangeObject: DELETED OBJECT")
        case .update:
            configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!, withEvent: anObject as! PT_Events)
            indexPathForManagedObjectChanged = indexPath
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.none)
            print("___controllerDidChangeObject: UPDATED OBJECT")
        case .move:
            configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!, withEvent: anObject as! PT_Events)
            indexPathForManagedObjectChanged = newIndexPath
            tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
            print("___controllerDidChangeObject: MOVED OBJECT")
    }
}
```

Then, in the Master Table View Controller's `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)` Fetched Results Controller Delegate method, I execute the following code...

```
guard let indexPathOfRowToSelect: IndexPath = indexPathForManagedObjectChanged else {
    return
}
indexPathForManagedObjectChanged = nil
tableView.selectRow(at: indexPathOfRowToSelect, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
```

This ensures that after inserts, updates and moves, the row that corresponds to the data in the Detail Table View is selected.

I use a Notification of type `UserDefaults.didChangeNotification`.

The observer is added in the Master Table View Controller's (**EDIT** was `viewDidLoad`, but now) `viewWillAppear(_:)` method. The observer is removed in the Master Table View Controller's `viewWillDisappear(_:)` method.

If the user changes one of the settings the Notification `observer` calls the following function...

```
@objc
func userDefaultSettingsDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

    if (notification.object as? UserDefaults) != nil {            
        NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>.deleteCache(withName: classCacheName)
        fetchedResultsController = nil
        tableView.reloadData() 
    }
}
```

**Problem**

On first run of the Master Table View Controller there is a Notification that calls the `userDefaultSettingsDidChange` method, but it calls this AFTER the first run through of the Fetched Results Controller Delegate methods in response to the first user interaction. This despite no change to the user defaults.

The issue occurs on simulator and on device.

I've added a stack of `print()`s (removed for ease of reading code) to track what is happening in what order.

The console logs the `userDefaultSettingsDidChange` function as executing AFTER the Fetched Results Controller Delegate methods have completed - BUT only on first run.

Because of this, the call to `reloadData` wipes out my previous call to `selectRow`.

**Solution**

I can wrap my call to the `selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` instance method in the Master Table View Controller's `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)` Fetched Results Controller Delegate method to include a slight delay...

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()

    guard let indexPathOfRowToSelect: IndexPath = indexPathForManagedObjectChanged else {
        return
    }
    indexPathForManagedObjectChanged = nil
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.20
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {       
        self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPathOfRowToSelect, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.none)
    }
}
```

This works!

But - I'm not satisfied.

I've done a lot of reading but for some reason, cannot seem to understand what is happening in `NotificationCenter` that is causing this ghost update to user settings despite no update.

Could someone please explain why I'm seeing this delayed "update" to user settings that is wreaking havoc on only the first user interaction in my UI?